# eclipse- "show in project explorer" option is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno for my java development and everything was working fine.
Just I restarted my system and now "Show in Project Explorer" option is not working. Nothing happens when I do this. I tried to refresh the work space and restarted the eclipse as well, but nothing is working for me. Any solution would save a lot of my time.

Thanks,

Comment: try : windows > reset windows

Comment: You mean reset perspective? I tried but not working.

Comment: try upgrading to latest Juno service release which currently SR2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Navigator instead, some people actually prefer it.

**Window-ShowView-Navigator**

It is almost the same as the project explorer, just shows all of the files, also, try the project explorer using the same steps.

The package explorer is basically the same thing as the project explorer.

If this does not work, please correct me.

Comment: Hi Dilan,
Navigator worked for me :) It serves the the basic need. But still project explorer and package explorer are not working.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Window -> Reset Perspective` (or) `Window -> Show View -> Others -> Java -> Package Explorer`

[image]

Comment: Windows->reset perspective there you go, just like that

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `Show in > Project Explorer` Eclipse tries to show you the current element of the outline. Click e.g. at the end of the page so that the cursor is positioned after the last bracket **and it will always work**:

[image: It will work when the cursor is placed correctly]

Comment: Good answer @Hannes Schneidermayer.  Several years later, but who cares - for me, I needed it now, it friggin' works - and in PROJECT EXPLORER as the asker (@Lakshmikantha) originally requested.  Also w/ an explanation as to why (outline).

Comment: @user1172173 Glad it helped you!

Comment: It is a TWO THOUSAND TWENTY ONE on the planet EARTH and still not working for me!

Comment: @АлексейХилаев Eclipse is a sinking ship. *Unusable garbage* for more than 5years now. Switch to IntelliJ already.